# showing that $\lim_{n \to \infty} {\sqrt [n]{|n^s - n^{s+1}|}} = 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

As I was solving a problem I came across needing $\lim_{n \to \infty} {\sqrt [n]{|n^s - n^{s+1}|}}$ to proceed. ($s \in  \mathbb{Q}$)

Is there any quick way to show $\lim_{n \to \infty} {\sqrt [n]{|n^s - n^{s+1}|}} = 1$?

P.S.it would also suffice to show $\limsup_{n \to \infty} = 1$.

Comment: This all boils down to $n^{1/n}\to 1.$ Do you know this?

Comment: yeah, I kinda feel like an idiot now for asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ldots\xleftarrow[\infty\leftarrow n]{}\sqrt[n]{n^s}\sqrt[n]{|1-n|}=\sqrt[n]{|n^s-n^{s+1}|}\le\sqrt[n]{n^s}=\left(\sqrt[n]n\right)^s\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\ldots$$